# Did Newt ever catch his Billywig?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

In the film Fantastic Beasts, Newt is asked whether he's caught all the creatures that escaped from his trunk. He replies in the affirmative.

However in several early scenes we see a bright multi-coloured insect flitting around. This, I presume is a Billywig. We never see Newt recapture this animal.

Is there any evidence that he caught it off-screen? And if so, why was it featured prominently in the early scenes, only to be forgotten later? And if not, does the fact a Billywig is lose in New York tie into future stories in the franchise?

Comment: Aren't Billywig America's native creatures?

Comment: @ILoveYou Billywigs are native to Australia.

Comment: To someone who hasn't seen FB, that title *really* sounds dirty.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Probably

Although there's no further mention of the billywig in the screenplay after Newt sees it fly past the window, in a deleted scene called "[Newt Goodbye](http://dvdcompare.net/comparisons/film.php?fid=41552)" found in the Blu-Ray extras, we find Newt's ship steaming away from Ellis Island. A billywig (possibly the same one as earlier in the film) flies toward us from the ship. The implication is that despite his [new high-tech security system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qRpQ.png), more beasts have managed to escape from his case(!)

[image]

After flitting around for a few seconds, it then turns around and appears to return toward the ship.

[image]

**The implication is that billywigs have a "homing" instinct.**

Comment: Aren't you assuming too much? Your implication seems pure speculation.

Comment: @Mindwin - Sure. Maybe it's an entirely different billywig and maybe it's just heading back to the ship to taunt Newt :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems a seagull got to it first.

Answer (score 10):

It is not in the script book or the released film but a deleted scene available on the DVD/Bluray shows Newt's ship steaming away from New York and the Billywig still flying free.

I don't believe there is anything beyond this, but if a deleted scene qualifies, the answer is **no, Newt did not catch his Billywig again.**

Comment: I'm really sorry. In advance

Comment: @Valorum - What does that mean? Are you the down voter? I didn't think this was a bad answer as there is nothing else available. If it's particularly dreadful, I can delete it!

Comment: I'm meant that I'm sorry for using your answer is the jumping-off-point to post a better answer that contradicts it. For the record, I'm not the downvoter and I don't know why it attracted one.

Comment: @Valorum - Ah, well go ahead. For the knowledge!

Answer (score 9):

### According to director David Yates, it was eaten by a seagull.

> **SnitchSeeker: What do you think happened to the blue billywig that was flying around New York City? Because it wasn’t actually captured back.**
>
> **David Yates:** *Unfortunately it got eaten by a seagull. (All laugh) It got gobbled up by a seagull.*
>
> <sub>[David Yates, Eddie Redmayne, Dan Fogler talk 'Fantastic Beasts' plot points, Obscurus](https://www.snitchseeker.com/harry-potter-news/david-yates-eddie-redmayne-dan-fogler-talk-fantastic-beasts-plot-points-obscurus-106934/)</sub>